# Change colour of TLabel in FireMonkey iOS app, and add items to TStringGrid?

Tags: iphone, delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I managed to get Xcode (running as a VM under Windows) pushing an XE2 build FireMonkey iOS HD app to my (jailbroken) iPhone after XE-script-prep (creating the Xcode folder), with a valid company certificate.

Anyway, faking the native cocoa controls seems a little seedy, but sticking a TToolbar (panel with standard iPhone gradient), a couple of TSpeedButtons (which have this curious V slope thing going on), and a TStringGrid and you're almost in the realms of basic iPhone app design.

Drop a TLabel on the TToolbar for a caption and straight away you'll want to change the colour, which there doesnt appear to be a property for.  Yeah but it's all style (TLayout) driven now I hear you say, which is what I thought, but the style editor doesnt have a colour (color!?) property within TLayout or TText aspects of the Style Designer.

Shoe-horning a second question which is just as quick, I dropped a TStringGrid on there and thought I'd dynamically set the rows, so I created a string column, set the RowCount to 6, then set the

```
Cells[1, n] := 'Row ' + IntToStr(iLoop);
```

...with no effect (I also tried Cells[0, n], in case it was a zero-based list).

Am I going mad?

*Still stumped on connectivity (how do you talk to anything outside the iPhone!?), and the performance of spinning a 48x48 image with a TFloatAnimation on an iPhone 4 was quite frankly appalling.  But I'm optimistic, we've got this far!*

Comment: I know it's easier for you, but I don't know the answer to all your questions.    I only know the answer to one.   I would recommend splitting your 3 questions up.... TLabel, StringGid, and Connections

Comment: Thanks Robert, yes I knew doing that was a mistake, sorry.  Since then I got a bunch more (not being asked here) like TStringGrid font or column header, properties are either missing or dont seem to work.  Have a good weekend, we certainly are all learning!!

Comment: This question should be edited to contain only a single item, and the other two questions moved to stand on their own. As is, it's almost possible to mark as answered, because you have three distinctly different topics. If a different person answers each question here, which one do you mark as the right answer? (For instance, I have sample code, for adding columns to the grid. I don't know offhand the answer about the label color or connectivity, so I'm not posting the answer to the columns question.) Please edit it, or I'll have to vote to close it as "not a real question". Thanks. :)

Comment: Connectivity: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439974/what-networking-components-are-available-for-firemonkey-ios-apps - that part is a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

This works fine for me.

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i:= 0 to 6 do
  begin
    StringGrid1.Cells[0,i] := 'Row:' + IntToStr(i);
  end;
end;
```

I noticed you had both `n`and `iLoop` wich one was the loop variable?

As to the color setting Roberts answer works designtime, if you want to set it in code you can do `Label1.FontFill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Beige;`

better way.

```
Label1.ApplyStyleLookup;
Label1.FontFill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.White;
```

But I think the correct approach would be to give FontFill a setter function like:

```
function GetFontFill: TBrush;
begin
  if FNeedStyleLookup then ApplyStyleLookup;
  Result := FFontFill;
end;
```

Comment: Excellent spot, thanks Peter.  Just uninstalling\reinstalling XE2 for Update 1!  This gives 2x or 3x FM iOS performance boost, now that's better!

Answer (score 3):

To change the color of a Label you need to use the Style.

Right Click on the Component and select Edit|Custom Style...

Then expand the Tlayout to find and select the  TText

Then adjust the `Fill` Property to change the color.

Comment: In Delphi XE8, the `TText` style doesn't have a `Fill` property. Not sure about older versions.