# How do you update TStringGrid cells in Delphi XE3, Firemonkey2

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

I've seen this question asked as part of another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531973/change-colour-of-tlabel-in-firemonkey-ios-app-and-add-items-to-tstringgrid) before, so know it can't just be me...if I open a new FireMonkey2 HD app, add a TButton and TStringGrid, then add this to the button on click event, NOTHING happens in the grid when I click the button!

```
procedure TForm33.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i:= 0 to 6 do
   begin
     StringGrid1.Cells[0,i] := 'Row:' + IntToStr(i);
   end;
   stringgrid1.UpdateColumns;
   stringgrid1.SetFocus;
 end;
```

Any ideas ?
PS I've also tried using TStringGrid.OnGetValue and it still won't show anything in the StringGrid.

Having looked further into the TStringGrid source code, C is nil so the Cells are never being set.

```
procedure TStringGrid.SetValue(Col, Row: Integer; const Value: TValue);
var
  C: TColumn;
begin
  C := Columns[Col];
  if Assigned(C) then
  begin
    C.UpdateRowCount(RowCount);
    C.SetCells(Row, Value);
  end;
```

I appears there are no Columns in the "virgin" StringGrid, so how do you add them ? There is a r+w RowCount property but ColCount is readonly...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must add at least a column to the [`TStringGrid`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/FMX.Grid.TStringGrid) in order to add data to the cells, you can do this in runtime

```
StringGrid1.AddObject(TStringColumn.Create(Self));
```

or in design time using the Items Designer

[image]

Comment: Doh! Thank you...Couldn't see that bit of info in any web examples.

Comment: So where is the Items Designer? I'm not finding documentation about this other than to double click on something else I don't know about.